# pytorch autograd obstructs script from terminating

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

Whenever I call autograds `backward` my script never terminates. `backward`is not per se blocking, all lines after it are still executed, the script just does not terminate. It appears that there is some sort of working thread in the background which hangs, but I was not able to find any information about it.

I originally encountered the problem while training neural networks, however I eventually found a very short example with the same behavior:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
y = x * 2
print(y)

gradients = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float)
y.backward(gradients)
print(x.grad)

print("all done")
```

When I remove the `backward` line, the script finishes as expected. Otherwise I see a process call `python` in the task manager, if I terminate it by hand, the script execution also terminates.

I installed pytorch on Windows 7 using conda (`conda create --name grad_test pytorch -c pytorch`) in the most recent, stable version (python 3.7, pytorch 1.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

It still exists now, seems to be Windows 7 specific issue.

Comment: Related github issues: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/48888 and https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29383